# Extending the Array class breaks my code

Tags: javascript, oop

If I remove the declaration of nothing() from the code blow- everything is fine. But why extending the Array class breaks the code of MyClass?

```
Array.prototype.nothing = function()
{
    alert('Morning');
}   

function MyClass()
{
    var methods = ['hello', 'hey'];
    for (var i in methods)
    {
        this[methods[i]] = function()
        {
           alert('This is method ' + methods[i]);
        }
    }
}


var c = new MyClass();
c.hello();
```

It breaks, because the alert is not showing:

> This is method hey

but:

> This is method function()
>   {
>   alert('Morning'); 
>   }

Comment: Breaks...as in what error?

Comment: @tymeJV Sorry, updated by question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below but here's the issue: you're tripping over the fact that the variable "i" is in the closure and is shared by all those function instances created in the constructor.

Now, what you're doing is creating a function for each of the property names (including the property whose name is the text of that "nothing" function, but that's sort-of only tangentially relevant). The last property name that'll turn up in that `for ... in` loop is the name "nothing" (though there's no guarantee in the language spec that the loop will traverse the property names in any particular order). After that, the loop exits, with the final value of "i" being the string "nothing".

Now, later, when you call `c.hello()`, that little function has access to the variables "i" and "method" from the original call to the constructor function. What's the value of "i"? It's still the string "nothing", so what the `hello()` function gives you is the value of `methods["nothing"]`, which is the text of that function.

Avoiding a `for ... in` loop will *partially* solve the problem, but not completely. The `.forEach()` method however will work, because each of the created functions will have it's own private `name` that will never change.

---

When you add that property to the Array prototype, it'll turn up as one of the property names in your `for ... in` loop. Because of that, one of the values of "i" will be "nothing", since after you extend the Array prototype the string "nothing" will be a property name of any array. Your variable "methods" is, of course, an array. Thus in the loop, at some point "i" will be "nothing", and `methods["nothing"]` is that function. Passing the function to `alert()` causes its source code to be folded into the `alert()` text.

You can avoid the problem with a test:

```
for (var i in methods)
{
    if (methods.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        this[methods[i]] = function()
        {
           alert('This is method ' + methods[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Better yet, don't use a `for ... in` loop at all on Array instances - it's never really a good idea (and I probably shouldn't have typed the above):

```
for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; ++i) {
   // etc
}
```

Finally there's `.forEach()`:

```
var newInstance = this;
methods.forEach(function(name) {
  newInstance[name] = function() { alert('This is method ' + name); };
});
```

Comment: thank you for this advice, I will surely use it, but it doesn't help here. I updated by question- the alert is showing wrong text.

Comment: @Tom Yes, it's showing the wrong text because your code is not adequately testing the object property names. Have you actually tried the code I suggested?

Comment: @Tom I'll extend the answer with a little more explanation.

Comment: Yes, I did, but my "nothing" function is not declared in MyClass, so there is no collision

Comment: @Tom it's declared on the Array prototype, and "methods" is an array!

Comment: When I remove the whole declaration of "nothing" from my first lines, then MyClass is showing the text the way it should.

Comment: @Tom good grief please reload the page and read my answer again.

Comment: @Pointy is right, the problem are your variables scopes. You added a method 'nothing' to Array's prototype, and then you create an Array when you declare your `methods` variable. And since you added 'nothing' to Array's prototype - it will appear in every single array that you'll ever create.

Comment: Yes, methods is an array, but I don't see why adding a method to the array type changes the way MyClass behaves. I am not even using this method "nothing" anywhere.

Comment: @Tom you're using a `for ... in` loop on an array. When you do that, the index variable ("i" in this case) will iterate through all the property names visible on the object, **including properties from the object's prototype.**  Thus, one of the values of "i" in that loop will be the name of that function you added to the Array prototype.

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk But my loop should still alert "This is hello". And it doesn't.

Comment: @Tom **OH OK sorry I see now.**

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. I understand that. But then the loop should give me 3 elements: hello, hey and the nothing method. And when I call hello() on my object it doesn't print "This is method hello".

Comment: @Tom wow, this question is like a collision of two of the most common JavaScript pitfalls on Stackoverflow :) I'm updating the answer now.

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks, I see the problem now. It's the scope of variable. methods[i] in my alert sees the last element of methods, not the one I wanted.

Comment: @Tom yup!!  Thanks for this; it's gotten me all woken up now :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that's you want:

```
function MyClass()
{
    var methods = ['hello', 'hey'];
    for (var i in methods)
    {
        if (methods.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            this[methods[i]] = (function() { 
                var method = methods[i];

                return function() {
                    alert('This is method ' + method);
                };
            })();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still won't work, because the variable "i" is still coming from the closure.

Comment: Oh durr I missed the `return function` part. Yes this will fix it :) (Though it'd still be better to avoid `for ... in`.)

Comment: @ilyamilosevic Thank you. It does what I need, but I think I will stick to forEach option as it is shorter a bit. You posted a nice trick I'll surely remember :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with using `forEach`, but I thought that the main problem wasn't in that, so I didn't change it.